# InflateException: Binary XML file line #7

Tags: java, android, xml

Help please, I'm new in Android.
I serch in this page for an answer, but i can't fixed.

This code should be result this:
[click](http://www.androidcurso.com/images/unidades_android/googlemaps8.png)

but result the next error code

**Log cat error**

```
    07-25 17:38:49.111: E/AndroidRuntime(22380): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-25 17:38:49.111: E/AndroidRuntime(22380): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lautaromap/com.example.lautaromap.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
07-25 17:38:49.111: E/AndroidRuntime(22380):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2114)
07-25 17:38:49.111: E/AndroidRuntime(22380):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
07-25 17:38:49.111: E/AndroidRuntime(22380):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
07-25 17:38:49.111: E/AndroidRuntime(22380):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
07-25 17:38:49.111: E/AndroidRuntime(22380):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-25 17:38:49.111: E/AndroidRuntime(22380):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-25 17:38:49.111: E/AndroidRuntime(22380):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
07-25 17:38:49.111: E/AndroidRuntime(22380):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-25 17:38:49.111: E/AndroidRuntime(22380):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-25 17:38:49.111: E/AndroidRuntime(22380):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
07-25 17:38:49.111: E/AndroidRuntime(22380):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
07-25 17:38:49.111: E/AndroidRuntime(22380):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-25 17:38:49.111: E/AndroidRuntime(22380): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
07-25 17:38:49.111: E/AndroidRuntime(22380):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:710)
07-25 17:38:49.111: E/AndroidRuntime(22380):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
07-25 17:38:49.111: E/AndroidRuntime(22380):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
07-25 17:38:49.111: E/AndroidRuntime(22380):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
07-25 17:38:49.111: E/AndroidRuntime(22380):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
07-25 17:38:49.111: E/AndroidRuntime(22380):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:318)
07-25 17:38:49.111: E/AndroidRuntime(22380):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1925)
07-25 17:38:49.111: E/AndroidRuntime(22380):    at com.example.lautaromap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
07-25 17:38:49.111: E/AndroidRuntime(22380):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5203)
07-25 17:38:49.111: E/AndroidRuntime(22380):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
07-25 17:38:49.111: E/AndroidRuntime(22380):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2078)
07-25 17:38:49.111: E/AndroidRuntime(22380):    ... 11 more
07-25 17:38:49.111: E/AndroidRuntime(22380): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4323000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
07-25 17:38:49.111: E/AndroidRuntime(22380):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.t(Unknown Source)
07-25 17:38:49.111: E/AndroidRuntime(22380):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
07-25 17:38:49.111: E/AndroidRuntime(22380):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.B(Unknown Source)
07-25 17:38:49.111: E/AndroidRuntime(22380):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.A(Unknown Source)
07-25 17:38:49.111: E/AndroidRuntime(22380):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
07-25 17:38:49.111: E/AndroidRuntime(22380):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.gW(Unknown Source)
07-25 17:38:49.111: E/AndroidRuntime(22380):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
07-25 17:38:49.111: E/AndroidRuntime(22380):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
07-25 17:38:49.111: E/AndroidRuntime(22380):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
07-25 17:38:49.111: E/AndroidRuntime(22380):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
07-25 17:38:49.111: E/AndroidRuntime(22380):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:290)
07-25 17:38:49.111: E/AndroidRuntime(22380):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:682)
07-25 17:38:49.111: E/AndroidRuntime(22380):    ... 21 more
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.lautaromap;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" 
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.lautaromap"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.lautaromap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.lautaromap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAgZ5rKrb4V3Gj4QI1Xhr44fzAAGFSTIj8
            " />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.lautaromap.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: The error message specifies at least one problem with your code: `The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4323000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is quite straightforward. Just add this:

```
<meta-data 
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
      android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

into your manifest within the  element.